# Is there a way to export and import models rather than re-running them every session?

Tags: r, lme4

I have to run a lot of computationally intensive models for work (e.g poisson-family glmers with lots of random effects nested within other random effects), make predictions from them and then plot them as graphs. Sometimes my managers want me to make changes to the predictions or graphs, but the models sometimes take hours to run. Is there a way I can save time by exporting and importing the model objects rather than having to rerun them within the script every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
```

Save the model object

```
saveRDS(glm.D93, file="glm.rds")
rm(glm.D93)
```

Retrieve the model object

```
glm.D93 <- readRDS("glm.rds")
anova(glm.D93)

# Analysis of Deviance Table

# Model: poisson, link: log

# Response: counts

# Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          # Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
# NULL                          8    10.5814
# outcome    2   5.4523         6     5.1291
# treatment  2   0.0000         4     5.1291
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save any object using `saveRDS(object, filename)`, and read it back into R using `readRDS(filename)`. See `?saveRDS`.