# Save Export and Import models via human readable file

Tags: r, predict

I am working with secure datasets and a safe data environment, and producing models from them, e.g. Cox proportional hazard models which are safe to export
i.e. model <- coxph(survobject, y ~ x + a+ b + c).

I can use grid.expand on all possible values of x, a, b, c and predict(model, grid) to visualise what the model is saying about the risk distribution.

However, I'd like to export the models and carry out all the model visualisation outside the safe space.
What is the best way to export the model, save the model and import the model so I can use predict at a later time on new data without access to the original data. *Bearing in mind* this file needs to be readable by a human to assess that it is a datasafe export and does not include any of the original (sensitive) data.

I note that you can export the model as an RDS file.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744797/is-there-a-way-to-export-and-import-models-rather-than-re-running-them-every-ses]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744797/is-there-a-way-to-export-and-import-models-rather-than-re-running-them-every-ses%5D)
However, when opening this with notepad it is unreadable.

I have already exported all the coefficients, i.e. the outputs from glance and tidy (both exponentiated and not). Is there any way to reconstruct a model that can carry out predict from this data?

How can I export the model in a human readable file, perhaps via unlist, saving in excel and then reconstructing the model?

I know how to calculate predictions from linear models but not from CoxPH models.